# Magento 2 : Need to display log in custom file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.1

I want to write custom log in third party module, how can I achieve this by using Magento default classes and log functions.

I tried many solutions but no luck on third party module. I need to write own file in log directory.

Please help me if anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code to generate log file

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);

$logger->info('Test log here');
```

Comment: Okay thanks for your quick response on this, I will try and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is working perfectly.